# ZeroMQ: Waiting for a message without consuming thread

Tags: python, zeromq, messaging

I have some simple python code which waits for messages for a topic.

However...when running this, the python process will hog CPU. I know with other languages, such as with sockets, there is a way to wait for messages without eating the entire processing power. Essentially the thread just remains halted waiting for a response. Is that possible with ZeroMQ?

```
import zmq
import sys

port = "5556"
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    port =  sys.argv[1]
    int(port)

# Socket to talk to server
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)

print "Collecting updates from weather server..."
socket.connect ("tcp://localhost:%s" % port)

# Subscribe to zipcode, default is NYC, 10001
topicfilter = "10001"
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, topicfilter)

# Process 5 updates
total_value = 0
for update_nbr in range (5):
    string = socket.recv()
    topic, messagedata = string.split()
    total_value += int(messagedata)
    print ('{} {}'.format(topic, message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

The code above is not a reproducible MCVE/MWE-representation of the claimed problem.

First : the code explicitly blocks. Using a **`.recv()`**-method is blocking until any new, matching message arrives ( if ever ).

That does not overload the CPU. It just keeps sitting on the **`SUB`**-side waiting, until a first such message ( if any ) arrives.

If interested in a better scheme, do not use `.recv()`-method this way, but rather detect any such `POSACK`-acknowledgement with a **`.poll()`**-method & read a `POSACK`-ed case with **`.recv( zmq.NOBLOCK )`**-method.